# jQuery slider pause on video play and resume on video over

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have found this slider demo http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/ on slide 8 there is video i want when it comes to video it to start playing, its okay i can just embed video with autostart. but what the problem is that it keep scrolling even when video starts if you mouse out the slider.

How can you modify it to make slider pause while video still playing? In worse case i can just take custom time for that particular slide.

p.s. they do offer in config line for custom function, but i have no idea how to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#showcase").awShowcase(
    {
        auto:               true,
        interval:           3000,
        custom_function:    null /* Define a custom function that runs on content change */
    });
});
```

also in javascrip there is line

```
    if (options.auto && options.pauseonover)
    {
        showcase.mouseenter(function() { break_loop = true; clearInterval(myInterval); });
        showcase.mouseleave(function()
        {
            if (!pause_loop)
            {
                break_loop = false; myInterval = window.setInterval(autoChange, options.interval);
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT: 
Okay i found out there's 2 way't individual timeout for each slide, or to make image for video and upon clicking start video and pause slider or extend timeout of current slide.

```
the problem is when i type `onclick="function() { break_loop = true; clearInterval(myInterval); })"` it saying myInterval not found how do i access properties of slider?
```

Comment: This is going to depend on which player you end up using on your site.  Whether you're using vimeo or some other player will effect the stop and start behavior.

Comment: Youtube or Vimeo i dont care, why player matters though?